# Receber dados provenientes e submetidos por uma janela modal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu tenho a janela modal abaixo... não consigo receber os dados do submit da janela modal na página cadastrar.php... Desculpa pessoal não tenho muita experiência com javascript. Por favor me ajudem!

```js
java script:

<script>
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
        $('.submit').on('click', function()
          {  
            

          });

      });
    </script>
```

```html
Janela Modal

<div class="modal fade" id="resolverMulta" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form method="POST" action="cadastrar.php" id="form_Confirm" autocomplete="off">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmar Pagamento da Multa</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="admalert" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none;"> <strong>Erro!</strong> Administrador ou Senha Errados. </div>

        <label id="lbl_oco">Ocorrência: <span class="oco" style="color: red"></span></label><br>
        <label id="lbl_matri">Matrícula: <span class="matri" style="color: red"></span></label><br>
        <label id="lbl_mult">Multa: <span class="mult" style="color: red"></span></label>
        
        <br> 
        <br>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Autenticação</h4>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="inputAdministrador">Adm</label>
                       <input class="form-control" id="inputAdministrador" name="adm_nome" type="text" placeholder="Adm" style="height: 42px; backface-visibility: none;">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label for="inputadmPass">Password</label>
                       <input class="form-control" id="inputadmPass" name="adm_pass" type="password" placeholder="Senha" style="height: 42px;">
        </div>
      
        
        
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <a type="submit" class="btn btn-primary confirmar">Confirmar</a>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Conhece [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?

Comment: Augusto tenho algum conhecimento de jquery.

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde.
Cara desse jeito não funciona quando vocẽ utiliza action no form ele gera uma requisição fazendo reload na tela.

a melhor maneira é usar um ajax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form e depois que a requisição for devolvida se estiver tudo certo ai você fecha o modal.